# Difference between azure function and azure static web app? How it works?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-account, azure-static-web-app

What is the difference between azure function and azure static web app?
As I am new in azure. I think both save there content files in azure storage account. When any request come first it goes to storage account then it excute the request. Could please explain how it works?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two are totally different offerings.

**Azure functions** is a part of server less offering on Azure which are are mainly used to easily build the apps you need using simple functions that scale to meet demand.

**Azure static web app** is an easy way to quickly host some static files – HTML and JavaScript – on a URL and have all the scaling and content distribution taken care of for you. The front end could be SPA using  Angular or React. The website retrieves data, if needed, you can use Azure Functions as functions as backend. A great feature of Azure Static Web Apps is that you don’t have to configure your CI/CD pipeline. This is done for you by Azure and Github using Git Actions.

Comment: To add to Sajeetharan's comments...
Azure functions are execution engine, aka you pass through something to it and it will give you an output or perform a desired action you programmed. Whereas Static web app is more of a website with basic functionality.. you can use backend engine of Azure functions to add some cool tricks to it as Sajeetharan mentioned

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan and Amandeep. Both services are serverless right?

Comment: Yes, they both are server less offerings.